# java swing ios like sliding menu

Tags: java, ios, swing, animation

I want to build a desktop app using java (and probably swing, but others are welcome) that I want to have iOS like animations. For example I would like to have a sliding-in panel-menu that shows up like the sliding-in menu of the facebook app in iOS.

I would also like to have popup-like panels that show up with animation like the notifications subView in facebook app of iOS.

Is there any working example on this?

Comment: You can take a look at http://filthyrichclients.org/

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at some of the animation frameworks

- [TimingFraemwork](http://java.net/projects/timingframework/pages/Home)
- [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)

I personally prefer TomingFrameowkr, but that's mostly because it was the first one I used and I have a bunch of support code to go with it.  You'll need to evaluate each and make your own choices

I'd also have a look at [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (Java 7) or [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/) (earlier Jave versions) and/or have a good understanding of the [glass pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) and things like absolute layout